# How to predict a list of values with linear regression?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-regression

I want to predict the values ​​of Y as a function of X

```
#Formula for Regresion Linear
W = np.linalg.inv( X.T @ X ) @ X.T @ Y
```

Now I can predict values since I can do this.

`y_P = W @ [1, ValueToPredict]`

and it works. But I'd like to use this to predict a sequencie of values. For example:

```
Values_I_Want_To_Predict = np.array([ [1, 9], [1,10], [1, 11] ])
```

How can I use my matrix Values_I_Want_To_Predict with my vector (not sure if is a considered as vector since its shape es (2,1)) in order to predict all values of my matrix?

`# W = [-34.67062078   9.10210898]`

Comment: Try vectorizing your code. Refer - https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html

Comment: I assume your `X` matrix is shape `(2,n)`, with 1's in the 0th row, and x values along the 1st row.  If so, can't you just do `W @ Values_I_Want_To_Predict.T` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are finding the weights is calling analytical solution. To predict labels you can use:

`y_pred = W @ X.T`